# совершить абсурд

Tags: словосочетания

совершить абсурд
правильно ли это с точки зрения русского языка

Comment: Можете расставить необходимые знаки в вашем сообщении? Проверяйте текст перед отправкой, — примерно так говорится в Справке о сайте.

Answer (score 0):

в разговорной речи так не говорят